# PHP / Google Maps - Geofence

Tags: php, google-maps, geotagging

I am attempting to create a simple tracker using php and google maps. Right now I have the tracker working but I want it to detect proximity to certain markers. For example if the user is within 30m of the my "house" (a marker) the script will update it's status saying it is at "so and so's house". I would like this to be achievable in PHP. Would the best method be to detect the long / lat of each marker and create a simple perimeter around it, then detect if the users long and lat places within that perimeter. Are there examples of this around that I could possibly work from or mathematical equations.

Comment: Please do not write answers in the questions or use [SOLVED] in the title. If you've figured out the answer yourself, please post it in the answer box below. Since you're a new user with rep <100, you'll be able to do it in 7 more hours.

Comment: @Keiran Lovett what db are you using?Is there a chance that you can use postgresql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Haversine formula is what you're looking for. There's [an article on Google Code](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3.html) that describes how to use it with MySQL and PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Solution Used -

```
function calc_distance($point1, $point2)
{
    $radius      = 3958;      // Earth's radius (miles)
    $deg_per_rad = 57.29578;  // Number of degrees/radian (for conversion)

    $distance = ($radius * pi() * sqrt(
                ($point1['lat'] - $point2['lat'])
                * ($point1['lat'] - $point2['lat'])
                + cos($point1['lat'] / $deg_per_rad)  // Convert these to
                * cos($point2['lat'] / $deg_per_rad)  // radians for cos()
                * ($point1['long'] - $point2['long'])
                * ($point1['long'] - $point2['long'])
        ) / 180);

    return $distance;  // Returned using the units used for $radius.
}
```

I used the Haversine formula I found on another post.